# MariaDB Active Directory Authentication

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap, fedora, mariadb

I am having a problem authenticating into a MariaDB using AD.

This is what I have done so far:

1. Enabled plugin auth_pam

   ```
   MariaDB [(none)]> INSTALL SONAME 'auth_pam';

   MariaDB [(none)]> show plugins;
   +--------------------------------+----------+--------------------+-------------+---------+
   | Name                           | Status   | Type               | Library     | License |
   +--------------------------------+----------+--------------------+-------------+---------+
   | binlog                         | ACTIVE   | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL        | GPL     |
   | pam                            | ACTIVE   | AUTHENTICATION     | auth_pam.so | GPL     |
   +--------------------------------+----------+--------------------+-------------+---------+
   43 rows in set (0.00 sec)
   ```
2. Created a user on the db with a username that exists in AD

   ```
   MariaDB [mysql]> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO xyz IDENTIFIED WITH pam AS 'mariadb';
   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

   MariaDB [mysql]> select user, password, host from user;
   +--------------+-------------------------------------------+------+
   | user         | password                                  | host |
   +--------------+-------------------------------------------+------+
   | root         | *1114CDA5E6E               8254812 | %    |
   | xyz          |                                           | %    |
   +--------------+-------------------------------------------+------+
   5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

   MariaDB [mysql]>
   ```
3. Next I created `/etc/pam.d/mariadb`

   ```
   #%PAM-1.0
   auth       include  system-auth
   account    include  system-auth
   password   substack system-auth
   -password   optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so use_authtok
   password   substack postlogin
   auth        sufficient    pam_krb5.so use_first_pass no_validate
   ```
4. Now I log in to the machine with AD

   ```
   sh-4.2$ su xyz
   Password: 
   sh-4.2$ whoami
   xyz
   sh-4.2$
   ```
5. And finally tried to authenticate into MariaDB using LDAP. Takes about 20 seconds before claiming that

   ```
   sh-4.2$ mysql -u xyz --password=Tog4hP@ssw0rd
   ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'xyz'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
   sh-4.2$
   ```

Question is, I passed the password with the command. Why is Maria complaining that `(using password: NO)`?

Further, I see in  `tail /var/log/secure -f` a few lines which I think may shed some light

```
    May 28 15:58:40 localhost mysqld: pam_unix(mariadb:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=27 euid=27 tty= ruser= rhost=  user=xyz
    May 28 15:58:40 localhost mysqld: pam_krb5[3452]: error reading keytab 'FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab'
    May 28 15:58:40 localhost mysqld: pam_krb5[3452]: TGT verified
    May 28 15:58:40 localhost mysqld: pam_krb5[3452]: authentication succeeds for 'xyz' (xyz@******.**.ORG)
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues.

User should be created with VIA option, not with WITH

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'dbversity'@'%' IDENTIFIED **VIA** pam USING 'mariadb' REQUIRE SSL;

Secondly, your mariadb pam file should be like below.

> [root@dbversity.com ~]# cat /etc/pam.d/mariadb
>
> auth required    pam_krb5.so   minimum_uid=1000   no_user_check
>
> account required       pam_krb5.so  no_user_check
>
> [root@dbversity.com ~]#